# How to take the username of the user in Python without os.system() or error?

Tags: python, pycharm, os.system

I am writing a program where I am giving a small part:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess

whoami = subprocess.check_output("whoami", shell=True)
print whoami
os.chdir("/")
os.chdir("/home/"+whoami+"/Silly")
pwd = subprocess.check_output("pwd", shell=True)
print pwd
```

After executing the program I got this:-

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/rocky/PycharmProjects/Silly/Tester2.py
rocky
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/rocky/PycharmProjects/Silly/Tester2.py", line 8, in 
<module>
os.chdir("/home/"+whoami+"/Silly")
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/rocky\n/Silly'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Using PyCharm by JetBrains on Linux. When ever I take the username I get the "\n" with the user name. I tried using

```
whoami = whoami[:-2]
```

But failed.

Comment: Remember that you can use `~` to immediately get to the home directory on Linux systems.

Comment: Thank you @Wintro but I knew that but the user has to decide which user's home directory. Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is because whoami is a byte stream with a '\n' at the end.

use `strip()` to remove '\n' from whoami object.

And convert it to string by decoding it in utf-8.

```
whoami = whoami.strip().decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Thank you @Vikash! This answer helped me.

Comment: you are welcome. Also a good way to get username is in the link to duplicate question marked.

Comment: Sure! I'll just peek it.

Comment: @KarthikSrivijay if the answer helped please mark the tick box or up vote. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure @Vikash! I'll do it now.